# CSS Progress Tracker Not Filling Up

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a progress tracker in SCSS that will fill up according to the width. I know that the width is being passed in, as when I inspect the element it says the appropriate width. However, for some reason the animation isn't running.

The SCSS is:

```
.checkout-bar
  li.active:after {
    @include green-stripe;
    @include inner-shadow;
    content:"";
    height: 15px;
    left: 16%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    z-index: 0;
    span.bar-animation {
      -webkit-animation: myanimation 3s 0 forwards;
    }
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

The HTML is:

```
<div className="checkout-wrap">
   <ul className="checkout-bar">
     <li className="visited first">Received Message</li>
     <li className="visited">Splitting Message</li>
     <li className="visited">Publish on Call</li>
     <li className="previous visited">Ready to Send</li>
     <li className="active" style={{'width': percent + '%'}}>Sending Message
       <span className="bar-animation">&nbsp;</span>
     </li>
     <li className="next">Done</li>
   </ul>
</div>;
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is that SCSS or SASS or what is it?

Comment: It's SCSS. Edited to fix the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You only defined the last keyframe. In order for the animation to run you have to define a `from {}` aspect aswell. I added a little JSFiddle below to show what I mean.

```
.progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
  height:50px;
  width: 0%;
    animation-name: myanimation;
    animation-duration: 4s;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    from {
     width:0%; 
    }
    to {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v4nbqznt/

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because if I put the `-webkit-animation: myanimation` in the `li.active:after` then it works perfectly even without specifying from. The issue with this is that it fills the width to 100% of the `li`, which is not right. There's some issue with the span tag, and I'm just not sure what it is.